# Fetching real time data from continuously changing MySQL database table

Tags: python, mysql, api

I have a database (MySQL) table which contains applications with `app_id` column as a primary key. Now these applications have status which changes time to time whenever user does any activity and that status gets updated continuously (e.g. : suppose there is `app_id = 1` with `incomplete` status. After some time user does an activity and status changes from `incomplete` to `complete` in that table. So the same thing should be updated on third party API when we connect this table to API.)

What i am trying to do is to get data from that table and forward it to the third party API using python. Whenever there is a change in the status in that database table, the same update will be on that third party API.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `table on third party API` mean?an API doesn't contain tables as far as I know..

Comment: not table like database table....Its a dashboard where information will be updated.

Comment: See whether [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/86d45fc8-d55d-48c3-810d-36ff2ca65b1e/database-polling?forum=sqlgetstarted) is helpful.